# How do I upgrade to the next cordova version?

Tags: cordova, version, visual-studio-cordova

My project was built when Cordova 3.5.0 was out. Cordova 3.6.0 is out now.

How do I upgrade Cordova in my project?

I already did "npm -g update cordova" but that does not seem to be the version CTP uses.

Comment: to create project with 3.6 use command line interface. MDA ctp 2.0 allows to create ly upto 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For CTP 2.0 you can edit the file platforms.js in %APPDATA%\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cord‌​ova-lib\src\cordova\platforms.js and update the versions of Cordova that should be used for each platform. You should check the github URLS listed in the file to see what versions are available and update the 'version:' elements as needed.

Using this method I changed the android section of platforms.js from :

```
'android' : {
    parser : './metadata/android_parser',
    url    : 'https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-android.git',
    version: '3.5.0'
},
```

to:

```
'android' : {
    parser : './metadata/android_parser',
    url    : 'https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-android.git',
    version: '3.5.1'
},
```

After editing delete the contents of the bld directory belonging to your project.
Start VS, load your project and perform a clean and then a build.
You can check the build output and verify that it downloads the new version of Cordova to use during the build process.

Answer (score 4):

CTP 2.0 of the MDHA apps only targets Cordova 3.5.0. Currently, there is no way to retarget your project to 3.6.0.

Comment: "For CTP 2.0 you can edit the file platforms.js in %APPDATA%\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cord‌​ova-lib\src\cordova\platforms.js"

Answer (score 1):

Multi-Device Hybrid Apps for Visual Studio CTP2.0 will use the source of 'Cordova version 3.5.0'. Even  updating Command Line Interface using the command, that you mentioned, will not affect the Multi-Device Source. Only downloading the Source using command (Command Line Interface) will get the latest version of Cordova.

Create New project using Command Line Interface to get latest version of Cordova (3.6.0): https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html

Comment: That's bad, well I'll see how long I'll have to wait for an update and let that decide if i'm going with a Visual Studio project or using the command line interface of Cordova. (BTW if you could fix your sentences to make more sense I will choose your answer)

Comment: Let me do changes with my answer @StarQuake

Comment: Changed it for you. You only have to accept the changes ;)

Answer (score 0):

I received a warning from Google Play because the Cordova Version of my application:

"You should upgrade to Apache Cordova 3.5.1 or higher as soon as possible. For more information about the vulnerabilities, and for guidance on upgrading Apache Cordova, please see http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2014/08/04/android-351.html."

So, I also need a way to update cordova version in "Multi-Device Hybrid Apps for Visual Studio".
I submited it in connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/991242

Comment: They've answered the question. Yes, there is a way to update cordova. See the link https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/991242

Comment: "For CTP 2.0 you can edit the file platforms.js in %APPDATA%\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cord‌​ova-lib\src\cordova\platforms.js"

Answer (score 0):

I cried a lot while developing Cordova in VS. First I removed the 'bin', 'bld' and 'platforms' folders and restarted VS after every plugin/cordova change. Later-on I found it's easier to clear the cache. This will also do the job for Cordova version upgrade:

```
1) In VisualStudio project doubleclick config.xml
2) Click 'Platforms' and select Cordova CLI
3) Click 'tools' => 'Options'
4) Expand 'Tools for Apache Cordova' and click 'Cordova Tools'
5) 'Clear Cordova Cache' and click 'ok'
6) Rebuild the application
```